# Storing and retrieving a joda DateTime in this format YYYYMMDDHHMMSSFF

Tags: java, timestamp, jodatime

I have a `timestamp` datatype field called created in a derby database.

I'm using JAVA with the following insert call to insert the created field in the database:

`new Timestamp(new DateTime().getMillis());`

Two questions:

1. Not sure if this is possible but our requirements are that the created field is stored in this format:

   **YYYYMMDDHHMMSSFF**
2. We need to somehow retrieve the field (from step 1) from the database to a joda `DateTime` field in this format: **YYYYMMDDHHMMSSFF**

how do we go about doing #1 and #2 above in Java?

I have tried the below code in Java to retrieve the data right now but that is not how is needed:

```
Timestamp ts= (Timestamp)row.get("created");

DateTime storedatetime = new DateTime(ts);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: First to note: A Timestamp has no format for itself. Which sql-type has your db-column named "created"? CHAR or TIMESTAMP?

Comment: The sql-type for the db-column named "created" is TIMESTAMP

Comment: ResultSet has a method getTimestamp(). Where is the problem exactly?

Comment: If TIMESTAMP then try to use [row.getTimestamp("created")](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp-java.lang.String-) The described format YYYY... should just be an internal detail of database which the JDBC-driver hides for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... our requirements are that the created field is stored in this format: YYYYMMDDHHMMSSFF"

A timestamp is a value that represents an instant in time.  It is defined by its resolution (i.e. what's the smallest increment of time it can represent) but you should not care at all about how it is physically stored in a database.

A timestamp by itself does not have a format, but can be rendered for display in many different formats.

If the requirement really means *"the field must represent times with at least two digits precision"* then a standard database `timestamp` column will do just fine.

If the requirement is really *"the timestamp must be displayed in the format..."* then again a database `timestamp` will suffice, and you must ensure that whenever you output the value to an external medium (i.e. a report or web page) that you format it correctly.